# Unable to properly view full screen apps

Tags: fullscreen, maximized

I just installed Ubuntu and I'm new in it. I'm experiencing this bug that if I minimize an  app like the web browser and I try to maximize it again it doesn't go maximized. There are like some margins around it.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you saying that you had the window maximized, clicked the minimize button and then brought that app/window back up and it wasn't maximized anymore? 'Cause from the printscreen, the window doesn't appear to be maximized with some margin around it, but it looks like a normal floating/non-maximized window, and the button to maximize it is enabled. What happens if you click it?

Comment: @frippe it will flicker like the animation of going maximize and then it will go back from what the picture is shown

Answer (score 0):

try F11 where you are over the launched app

Or in command line :

```
yourbrowsername --kiosk
```

or

```
yourbrowsername --start-fullscreen
```

where yourbrowsername = firefox / chrome / chromium ...